# How to reduce CPU clock speed?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, monterey

How can I reduce my MacBook Pro 2015's CPU clock speed or power consumption? I want the battery to last a lot longer.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a duplicate of your other question.

[Make MacBook battery last as long as possible](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446456/make-macbook-battery-last-as-long-as-possible)

Apple designs its laptop for the best balance between performance and battery life.
There is very little you can do to make the battery life 'a lot longer' -- while still using it to do useful work.

Lowering the clock speed, if possible, would reduce what you are usefully able to do with your machine.

Apple claims 'up to' 9 or 10 hours 'wireless web browsing' or movie playback on 2015 models -- with the emphasis on 'up to'. You're not going to see more than that, whatever you do, and if your battery is 7 years old, you'll be lucky to get half that.